# Jasper report pdf has wrong name when downloaded in java

Tags: java, file, pdf, download, jasper-reports

I have an application(web one) where the users can view jasper reports. The only problem is that when they decided to save the pdf to their local computers, the pdfs have incorrect filenames. In Chrome they are named download.pdf and in Firefox they are named something like sgsgjsg.pdf.

What can I so in order for the files to be saved with the correct name ?

Note that I set the header type like this:

```
response.reset();
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"%s\"" + exportFile.getName());
inputFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fullPathFile);
outputFileOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put inside header filename the value what you needed.
For instance:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="\"download.pdf\"");
```

It is should works same for all browsers.

Comment: If you see my code above you will see that I set the header but it still ignores it.

Comment: I saw. But the filename is dynamic value in your code ( exportFile.getName() ).
I don't know how you created exportFile :)

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's dynamic. I tried with your line of code and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you provide all method.

Comment: What do you mean all method ? I'm interested only about the name of the file downloaded.

Comment: Exactly.
Because, I am sure, filename setted somewhere else :)

Comment: Man, even if I put a default string as the name named "jasper.pdf" it would still not use it/ignore it.

Comment: The problem only in the response. It is doesn't matter how you generate your file.
Just provide, how you create response and what you are writing in return